# What is a good word for a person selling to a merchant/shop?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a website which is a marketplace for in-game items with in-game currency.

Players can list items they are selling with a description and price. There's also a possibility to list items you are looking to buy the same way.

I thought a good word for the listing owner would be "Merchant" (is this right?). But what would a good word be for the person that buys or sells to the listing owner? Is client or customer a good word or can those only be used if you buy an item?

Sample:

Blackmarket advertises their item in a "listing".
Gamerboy69 buys an item from blackmarket.
Gamerboy69 is the customer/client. Blackmarket is the merchant.

Can i use the words in the same way if Gamerboy69 would sell an item to the owner of the listing, or is there another word i can use which will work?

Comment: Thanks for all the reactions, my question is answered. I'm not sure as why this is marked as "off-topic" and downvoted. This is about the English language and about the right word choice, the other text was the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you have described reminds me of second-hand dealers, and also of trading posts whose owner might buy furs and other valuable items from hunters etc. As the person who operates the listing actually buys items to re-sell them, the word you have suggested, "Merchant", is appropriate. "Trader" or "Dealer" would be other possible choices. "Fence" might be used if the goods had been stolen.

People who sell to the trader may be called "Suppliers", especially if they have an established relationship, or they may be just called "Sellers". Calling them "Clients" suggests that the trader is selling goods on their behalf, in which case the trader could be described as an "Agent" or a "Broker".

Customers are people who buy goods or services. A trader's suppliers do not normally fit this description, though there can be exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider words like vendor, broker, dealer, or distributor instead of merchant.

Comment: There’s always “seller.”

Answer (score 0):

They are a *Wholesaler*.

One who sells to a store that sells retail, to regular customers, is selling *wholesale* to the retailer. There are controls and customs to prevent regular folks from buying directly from the wholesaler. That is the business of the retailer.